# Cartesian Product as a tree

Tags: elementary-set-theory, trees

For any Cartesian product (at least for finite number of sets), I can associate it with a tree where the leaves are the sets and each node is the Cartesian product of node directly below it. For example, $(A \times B \times C) \times (D \times (E \times F))$ is the root of the following tree

[image]

In fact, if $\prod_{i_1} \prod_{i_2} \cdots \prod_{i_n} X_{i_1 i_2 ... i_n}$ a *finitely* nested Cartesian product, then I can always associate such expression with a tree with finite height (if one accepts that a node can have infinite number of child nodes) and vice versa. 
My question: is it possible to extend it to trees with infinite height? What would an infinitely nested Cartesian product look like?

Comment: Surely it would just look like an infinite tree?

Comment: Sure, but I also want to know is there a set construction of such infinitely nested Cartesian product (if exist)?

Comment: Also, it seems like I can never get to the root if I build up from the leaves, so it might not be even a tree?

Comment: Note that this tree structure really isn't about Cartesian products at all, but simply abstract operations parenthesized in a particular way.

Comment: Indeed, I was trying to prove that any 2 "parenthesizations" of Cartesian products is in bijective correspondence, but then I got stuck at the case when the tree height goes to infinite because I do not know what would infinite tree would be like